# Access Query to SQL Server - Error 53

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I'm having a weird issue where I try to query from one of my access file it's running into the SQL Server Error 53: Could not open a connection to SQL Server. But running the exact same query in another access file and I was able to run it perfectly fine. It's just a simple select query and I'm not sure why there is this discrepancy between the two access file. Does anyone know where I can investigate the issue further or has experience the same problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most probably not the query but has to do with linked tables, unless you are using a pass-through query.

Try to relink your tables. You can use the linked table manager. Right click on any table and choose Linked Table Manager. Choose "Select all" and then click "OK".